# Create a single pop up message box from the Worksheet_Calculate() sub

Tags: vba, excel

I have coded a pop up message in vba to show when a cell's value is between 0 and 90. However the message box appears multiple times since the cell's value is based on the number of days between x amount of months. For Example: If February of 2019 I have a cell value of 29 a pop up box appears like it should. When going out to July of 2019 the pop up box now appears 5 times since there are 5 months from Feb to July. I need the pop up box just to appear once no matter how many months are in between the previous month I was on before.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim Target As Range 
Set Target = Range("C49:C90")
Dim found As Boolean
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Target.Cells

    If cell.Value > 0 And cell.Value <= 90 Then
        found = True

    Exit For
    End If
Next
    If found = True Then
    MsgBox "There are employees approaching their expiration date!", vbExclamation, "WARNING!"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You must initialize your found variable to False.  If you calculate five times it must be initialized before the For Each to False and then the MsgBox pops up after the condition.  If you only want it to pop up once no matter how many times Calculate is called, you will be using another variable as a counter global in scope to Calculate and the calling code.  Counter initialized to Zero when you start loading the months, if message box pops then increment counter.  If found = True AND counter = 1 Then . . . . Basically you are running two control variables [should box pop?],[did box pop?]

Comment: Are the months all on one sheet and defined in your range?  Are you changing sheets?  No sheet is passed into your sub to define the .Range or .Cells so it will use whatever sheet is active in whatever workbook is active.

Comment: Yes the dates are listed in a different column. I then have a calendar drop down menu allowing the user to select any date they wish. After selecting the date the difference is taken and the output is the # of days. These days are what I'm using to compare in my vba code. I tried resetting with putting found = false but still no luck.

Comment: well that will only work for each individual call of Calculate.  You need  second value to record how many times the msgbox has popped up, You could make that true/false or only pop it at 1 and let it go as high as it wants.  You will have to show me the code where you call calculate and we can fix this in a jiffy.

Comment: This is the only code I have. I was thinking vba would just take that value and compare it to my criteria. I don't understand how or why it would take the cell's actual formula into account as well. I just was looking for a code that can execute this code every time user changes the date.

Answer (score 0):

Completely changing the answer for new information.  Rather than use the calculate, we will detect if the User changes the Date in Column B (say that is today's Date, if so this can be done with VBA, another day perhaps).  Column A would be the date of Expiry of the training. Column C is simply A-B, or the days between today and the expiration.

1) If the user has selected one cell AND The user has changed that cell (date)

2) check if the cell to the right (Column C) is in our range

3) Then check the cell to the right (Column C same Row) for 0 < Cell.Value <= 90

4) If it meets that criteria msgBox Pop (I added which row the msgBox is 
referring to for testing, you may take it out, but as you can see you could also refer to an Employee name here, or move info to an expiry list somewhere like another worksheet).

If none of those things are true, do nothing.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Range("C49:C90")

    'Check if the user has selected only one cell (for a date)
    'AND
    'Check that the calculation is in the range we are watching C49:C90
    If Selection.Count = 1 And Not Intersect(Target.Offset(0, 1), myRange) Is Nothing Then
        'We are assuming the date change is occuring in column B, so that offset to column C is 0,1
        'If the date that will change is not in B adjust accourdingly here
        If Target.Offset(0, 1).Value > 0 And Target.Offset(0, 1).Value <= 90 Then
            MsgBox "There are employees approaching their expiration date! at row:" & Target.Row, vbExclamation, "WARNING!"
        Else ' Do nothing
        End If
    Else 'Do Nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

[image: msgBox and report of Row]

Here is what I think you are after, checking your entire range if something changes and reporting accordingly.  This will report every row that meets your criteria after a slight modification.

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myRange As Range
Dim report As String
Dim myCell As Range

Set myRange = Range("C49:C90")
report = ""


    'Check if the user has selected only one cell (for a date)
    'AND
    'Check that the calculation is in the range we are watching C49:C90
    If Selection.Count = 1 And Not Intersect(Target.Offset(0, 1), myRange) Is Nothing Then
        For Each myCell In myRange
            If myCell.Value > 0 And myCell.Value <= 90 Then
            report = report & "There are employees approaching their expiration date! at row:" & myCell.Row & vbNewLine
            Else ' Do nothing
            End If
        Next
    Else 'Do Nothing
    End If

    If report <> "" Then
        MsgBox report, vbExclamation, "WARNING!"
    Else 'Do Nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

[image]
Happy Coding!

Comment: Thank you the code works as you said. Basically I have a date picker in excel from the developer tab. In one of my excel columns I have training expiration dates for each employee. So if one of their expiration dates is 11/21/2018 and from the date Picker I select 11/01/2018, that employee has 20 days until expiration. Which then I would like the message box to appear to give a warning. Now say I select a different date from the calendar picker. If it still matches the criteria in the code then the message box should appear again.

Comment: So basically if the data changes in my range and the range matches my criteria then a pop up box should appear once no matter how many cells match that criteria.

Comment: When you use the cells.value it won't use the formula.  You need to think about the logic you set up here.  If you change the data related to the formula in C49, it will run calculate which will bail out at the first cell meeting criteria. if not it keeps looking.  If you remove the boxPop logic you will be closer to what you want, but it will always check C49 first.  This is not the logic you want, if someone adjusts a date in a row, you want to check that C-row and report appropriately.  So we are now closer to understanding what you want.

Comment: To be thorough I am guessing you might want to go through the entire range and check for criteria and build a more comprehensive msgBox response.